# RefrenceError: error is not defined mern-stack project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, reference

[image]
I am making a mern stack project but i can't connect it to my database. I am trying to connect my project with mongodb but i am getting this error.

I have tired many things and look up o internet but can't find any solution.

Comment: This is because error in blue refers to a parameter in the function in which you haven't declared so essentially, you're not passing a parameter to the function body to use in your error message..

Change to:

`mongoose.connection.on('error', error => {
Console.log("Error connecting to the database", error.message);
});`

To fix issue.

Further explanation, 'error' refers to an event handler, error refers to the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Change the mongoose.connection.on('error',... to the following code.

```
mongoose.connection.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error('MongoDB connection error while trying to connect to DB:', error);
});
```

The problem was that you did pass the error as a parameter to the callback function, in that case, the compiler wouldn't recognize what "error" is.

Hope this helps!